# Unwanted Line Item in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sapb1

This one is probably really simple but im not seeing the solution. In SAP B1 I have a service call that has multiple sales orders linked to it. I only want the results from the most recent sales order however its throwing at me all the line items from every sales order attached to it. I can see in my code why its doing this but the solution just hasnt appeared before me.

I thought i could fix it by using a MAX(T4.DocNum) and grouping the select information however not only did that not work it also got rid of one of the lines i didnt want it to.

The code;

```
SELECT T1."callID",T3."ItemCode", T3."Dscription", T3.DocEntry,T2.SrcvCallId,T3.Quantity,T4.DocNum
FROM OSCL T1
LEFT JOIN SCL4 T2 ON T1."callID" = T2."SrcvCallID"
INNER JOIN RDR1 T3 ON T2."Object" = T3."ObjType" AND T2."DocAbs" = T3."DocEntry" AND T2."Object" = '17'
INNER JOIN ORDR T4 ON T4.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry
WHERE T1.callID = 11255
ORDER BY T4.DocDate DESC
```

The results;

[image]

As you can see the last result there comes from another associated linked document, i dont want this to appear.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: The expected result is all the rows EXCEPT for that last one that has a different DocNum (in this instance). If any service calls have more than one linked document of this type then the query should result in all the line items from that most recent linked document only.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i figured it out. Solution below for anyone else that may run into this problem.

I added an extra section to the RDR1 join to compare the SCL4.DocPstDate to the MAX docdate from a linked sales order which seems to have done the job.

```
SELECT T1."callID",
T3."ItemCode" AS 'OrderCode', 
T3."Dscription" AS 'OrderDesc', 
T3.DocEntry,
T2.SrcvCallId,
T3.Quantity AS 'OrderQty',
T4.DocNum
FROM OSCL T1
LEFT JOIN SCL4 T2 ON T1."callID" = T2."SrcvCallID"
INNER JOIN RDR1 T3 ON T2."Object" = T3."ObjType" 
AND T2."DocAbs" = T3."DocEntry" 
AND T2."Object" = '17' 
AND T2.DocPstDate = 
(SELECT MAX(A.DocDate) FROM ORDR A 
INNER JOIN RDR1 B ON B.DocEntry = A.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN SCL4 C ON C.DocAbs = B.DocEntry AND C.Object = '17' 
WHERE C.SrcvCallID = T1.callID)
INNER JOIN ORDR T4 ON T4.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry
WHERE T1.callID = 11255
ORDER BY T4.DocDate DESC
```